# How do you join the Golden Acorn Club?

Tags: hatch

In *Hatch*, while in the store, if you try to purchase something you can't afford, the shopkeeper mentions that there is the Golden Acorn Club. He says:

> If you purchase membership and join the club, you get 10% off
>   everything in the shop!

After that though, there is no mention of how to join or where to join. Is it something that comes up later in the game, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Official Hatch Facebook account:

> The Golden Acorn Club is made up by Max and he should stop talking about it next update

Source: https://www.facebook.com/hatchpet/posts/496429483788073